# Facebook iframe canvas app reload issue

Tags: facebook-apps

when someone visit my app, its asking permision. after user click login buton and authorizess app it still required manually refresh.

ı searched and found same problem with me:

basicly my problem is:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=108432

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=108498

ı tried this solution but its not working.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
window.location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Log a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

You cannot blindly reload the window.  Look at the response first (for debugging either put a `console.dir(response);` or a `debugger;` so you can see the structure of the response object .... or just read the documentation to see the structure)  and determine what it is telling you, only reload the page when necessary.